# How to map MX Master horizontal scroll wheel to keyboard buttons?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, logitech-mouse

[image]

I want to map my horizontal scroll to next/previous weapon in a game, but the game doesn't recognize horizontal scroll as a configurable key. Thus I want to map horizontal scroll to some random keyboard keys so that I can then map it to something useful inside the game.

Can I do this? The "Logitech Options" software is pretty limited. The only setting that kind of works is "Foward/Back" but then I can't use those two keys for something else.

Comment: At this point I fear the only way that is going to be possible is if someone creates a new 'uberoptions' for logitech options.

Comment: Have you tried autohotkey or something similar?

Comment: @Arete No, I haven't tried autohotkey. Does it support remapping horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To map the thumb wheel to trigger a keyboard button you need to use an additional software.

**How to remap buttons on the Logitech MX Master with autohotkey**

If you are using [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) you can [remap](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) buttons as you like.

A simple way to do remap the thumb wheel on the Logitech MX Master would be something like:

```
WheelRight::1
WheelLeft::2
```

This requires that you set the thumb wheel to "Horizontal scroll" in the Logitech Options software. In this case scrolling up with the thumb wheel will enter the number `2` and scrolling down will enter `1`. You have now remaped the thumb wheel to keyboard buttons.

**Why I would not use the thumb wheel as weapon switching in a game**

Still, I would not advise doing so because the thumb wheel on the MX Master is "freespin" only as opposed to the classic "ratchet mode" that a regular scroll wheel has. Using the script above will cause the remapped buttons to be triggered multiple times, even if you just slightly scroll on the thumb wheel.

In other words, you will easily end up getting a result such as:

```
2222222222222222222
111111111111111111111111111
```

Not very ideal for switching weapons in a cumputer game.

**Workaround**

A workaround would be to limit the input of the thumb wheel. Example:

```
#HotkeyInterval 1000
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 210

WheelRight::
    if (A_PriorHotkey != A_ThisHotkey or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 200)
        Send {1}
return

WheelLeft::
    if (A_PriorHotkey != A_ThisHotkey or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 200)
        Send {2}
return
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Will try this out with the rate limiter.